# wix4 wixproj document element name 'Project' is invalid

Tags: build, wix, wix4

When trying to build a `wix4` project using a the new wix toolset provided like this:

```
wix build -d Configuration=Debug MySetup.wixproj
```

I get this error:

> error WIX0048: The document element name 'Project' is invalid. A WiX source file must use 'Wix' as the document element name.

The project consists of 5 files. The `wixproj` file which I suspect will orchestrate the build. 3 `wxs` one that defines the basics from the setup and 2 which are filled up automatically by the `HeatDirectory` (defined in the wixproj). And last file is a `xslt`.

Those files have been migrated from wix3 using the VS 2022 HeatWave extension.

Did the migration miss some step or should I call the build in a different way?

To me looks like the wixproj file is missing some basic info to let the wix build command to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wix build` is for building WiX source files *without* MSBuild. To build a .wixproj, use `msbuild` or `dotnet build`.